# select most recent from non-normalized data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql which is not normalized and I need to query so that it groups by a certain field and gives the most recent row.

For example the table looks like

```
callername | callerdate | incoming | status
```

And I am trying to get all of the records which have their most recent status as `NotAnswered` and I can't figure out how you would do this, I can `GROUP BY` callername however I can't figure out how to get the most recent values.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: Does callerdate indicate most recent? Just `ORDER BY callerdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM 
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    callername,
    MAX(callerdate) AS callerdate
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    calledname
)
  AS mostRecent
    ON  mostRecent.callername = yourTable.callername
    AND mostRecent.callerdate = yourTable.callerdate
WHERE
  yourTable.status='NotAnswered'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.* FROM
YOURTABLE A,
( 
SELECT callername,callerdate,MAX(ID) AS ID 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE status='NotAnswered'
GROUP BY callername,callerdate
) B
WHERE A.ID=B.ID;
```

Comment: It's `callerdate` rather than `ID`. You need to alias `MAX(ID)` to something such as `as ID`.  You need an extra join predicate such as `AND A.ID = B.ID`.  You need the `status='NotAnswered'` in the outer query, not the inner.

Comment: But as per his question he needs the most recent status as 'Notanswered ' for each and every Callername.

Comment: My first 3 points have nothing to do with that. And my last point is because you are including all calls, no matter what their last state is. (You are showing the most recent `'NotAnswered'` state, not calls where the most recent state is `'NotAnswered'`.)

Comment: Your edit removed `A.callername = B.callername`. You need both that *and* `A.callerdate = B.callerdate`. ***Note:*** *The is no `id` field.*

Comment: Yes Dems.. But I am grouping them on callername.My query will get the most recent 'Notanswered' state for each callername.

Comment: Thanks from this I have enough information to work, you are right dems but I get the principle for now at least I will try a modified version of this I am writing.

Comment: I changed the query a bit.. Now this query will give the most recent NotAnswered state for each and every callername on each and every calldate.

Comment: @venk - You can't use the `id` column, as it doesn't exist. You can't filter by status on the inner query, you need to filter on the outer query (inner = most recent 'notAnswered', outer = most recent, where most recent is 'notAnswered'; there is a fundamental different there). And several other issues. I've added an answer to show the necessary layout.